# Get another field's type in Typescript class

Tags: typescript, this

I'm trying to get a field's type from another field in the same class. Specifically I'm trying to get a union of all possible property keys:

```
class Scene {
    cameras: Map<string, unknown> = new Map();
    activeCameraName: keyof typeof this.cameras;
}
```

However, this gives an error, saying `Cannot find name 'this'. ts(2304)`

I tried `keyof typeof self.cameras` but that seems to refer to `globalThis`
I also tried `keyof typeof Scene.cameras` but that obviously wouldn't work either.
Also came across the `ThisType` utility type — though the name suggests that I should be using this, I can't make sense of it.

How can I refer to a field from another field in a class?

Comment: The resulting type would just be `string` anyway. I feel like you want to look into using a generic on the class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to set expectations:  you cannot capture the type of Map keys (in the compile phase) based on the runtime contents of the map.

Secondly, to answer your question:

**to extract the type of map keys**:

```
type MapKey<M extends Map<any, any>> = M extends Map<infer K, any> ? K : never;
```

**To refer to another field in class**

```
class Scene {
    cameras: Map<string, unknown> = new Map();
    activeCameraName: MapKey<Scene['cameras']>; // infers string, as expected
}
```

Interred type string is expected, but still quite wide.

If you can limit the keys in the map to a union of well known strings, you can use:

```
class Scene {
    cameras: Map<'cam1' | 'cam2', unknown> = new Map();
    activeCameraName: MapKey<Scene['cameras']>;  // infers 'cam1' | 'cam2'
}
```

But in this case you may as well create a type for the union:

```
type CameraName = 'cam1' | 'cam2';
class Scene {
    cameras: Map<CameraName, unknown> = new Map();
    activeCameraName: CameraName;
}
```